# Problem involving circle

Tags: geometry

A railway line changes direction by 30 degree when passing round a circular arc of length 1500 m. What is the radius of the arc?    -Can someone explain the solution or Does this question solvable?

Comment: 30 degrees is one twelfth of a full circle. circumference is $2\pi$ times radius. can you take it from there?

Comment: i know but the circular arc does not mention from where to where

Answer (score 0):

You have to use the radian units of measure. This means that $30 ^{\circ} =\frac{\pi}{6}$. Since $s= r\theta$, where $s$ is the arc length and $\theta$ is the angle subtended by the arc in radians, you can simply plug in the numbers as $$1500=r\times\frac{\pi}{6}$$ 
This means that $r=\frac{9000}{\pi}$